# Cannot find Samba in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Dash

Tags: 16.04, samba, gui, unity-dash

Samba, `system-config-samba` and everything related to Samba is installed according to Synaptic and up to date. But I do not see it in the Dash. `/etc/samba/smb.conf` is present too. Also I did not find Samba in the new Ubuntu Software Center either.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem.
Having installed Ubuntu Mate 16.04

```
gksu system-config-samba
```

ended up with message:

```
SystemError: could not open configuration file `/etc/libuser.conf': Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
```

Funny ;-) solution: simply create the file:

```
sudo touch /etc/libuser.conf
```

restarted the server:

```
sudo service smbd restart
```

it worked! I can start the configuration tool from the ubuntu mate GUI menu now.

Answer (score 0):

Samba is a demon, you don't start it. It's running in the background. If you want to share files or access files simply use nautilus

To use the system config gui you need to have gksu installed:

```
sudo apt-get install gksu
```

Comment: yes but I want to open the system-config-samba GUI which appears as just Samba in the Dash to configure my shares. Even typing "sudo system-config-samba" in the terminal does not open it.

Comment: @REZ do you have the package gksu installed?

Comment: yes I just tried got this:

`File "/usr/sbin/system-config-samba", line 45, in <module>
    mainWindow.MainWindow(debug_flag)
  File "/usr/share/system-config-samba/mainWindow.py", line 121, in __init__
    self.basic_preferences_win = basicPreferencesWin.BasicPreferencesWin(self, self.xml, self.samba_data, self.samba_backend, self.main_window)
  File "/usr/share/system-config-samba/basicPreferencesWin.py", line 97, in __init__
    self.admin = libuser.admin()
SystemError: could not open configuration file `/etc/libuser.conf': No such file or directory`

Comment: i uninstalled Ubuntu and installed Ubuntu MATE...Things are fine now...ill delete this post...

Comment: @REZ: Could you please [edit] your post, when you want to add information? Especially file or program output [listings](/editing-help#code) (with the help of the `{}` button in the editor toolbar) are much more readable there; alternatively you can use a [pastie service](//paste.ubuntu.com/) for longer listings and include the link of your pastie in your question. Overall it’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. 
Having installed Ubuntu Mate 16.04, tried to open the GUI samba configuration,
nothing happended.

tried in shell

```
gksu system-config-samba
```

ended up with:
"SystemError: could not open configuration file /etc/libuser.conf': No such file or directory` "

My workaround: created the file:

```
sudo touch /etc/libuser.conf
```

restarted the server:

```
sudo service smbd restart
```

Now I can start the configuration tool from the ubuntu mate menue.